# Angular $http get not working.

Tags: angularjs

So my file.json is :

```
[
    { 
        'id' : 1,
        'name' : 'img/1.jpg' 
    },
    {
        'id' : 2,
        'name' : 'img/2.jpg' 
    },
    {
        'id' : 3,
        'name' : 'img/3.jpg' 
    },
    {
        'id' : 4,
        'name' : 'img/4.jpg' 
    },
    {
        'id' : 5,
        'name' : 'img/5.jpg' 
    }

]
```

And my controller is :

```
app.controller("MyCtrl", ["$scope", "$http", function($scope, $http){
    
    $http.get("file.json").then(function(data){
        $scope.template = data;
    
    });
    
}]);
```

So from my html page im calling the controller and doing a ng-repeat but not working:

```
<div class="container" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
<div ng-repeat="path in template.names">
<div class="inner">
    <img ng-src="{{path.name}}">
</div>
</div>
```

I keep getting error in console:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your JSON is invalid, you need to use double quotes `"` rather than single quotes `'`

Also, because you are using `then()` the `data` you're after will be wrapped inside a `response` object, so you will have to update that part of your code as follows:

```
$http.get("file.json").then(function(response){
    $scope.names = response.data;
});
```

And then update your `ng-repeat` as @Anonymous suggests:

```
<div ng-repeat="path in names">
```

And change this part (the `{{ }}` are not necessary here):

```
<img ng-src="path.name">
```

Comment: Followed this. `<div ng-controller="MyCtrl" ng-repeat="path in names">
 <p>{{path.name}}</p>
</div>` Even this is not working.

Comment: Hmm, strange, can you do a `console.log(response)` (inside of success callback) and post back what that returns?

Comment: Looks fine, so now you should be able to assign `response.data` to the `$scope` variable that you're using in your `ng-repeat`. Failing that can you do a `{{ names }}` in your view and see what that outputs.

Comment: I did the same: `$http.get("file.json").then(function(response){
    $scope.names = response.data;
});` and in the html `<div ng-repeat="path in names"> <p> {{ path.names }} </p> </div>. But nothing is displayed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135474/discussion-between-somename-and-matthew-cawley).

Answer (score 1):

It should be `<div ng-repeat="path in template">`, not `<div ng-repeat="path in template.names">`.
And also json standard for string is double quotes.

Comment: I did that. Nothing is showing. I tried: `<div class="container" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
<div ng-repeat="path in template">
<div class="inner">
    <p>{{path.name}}</p>
</div>
</div>` But nothing is showing. Nothing in the console also.

Comment: @Somename @Anonymous is correct in that you should change your `ng-repeat`, but you also need to change how you retrieve your `data` as it will be wrapped inside a response object.

Answer (score 0):

try using this:

```
$scope.template = JSON.parse(data);
```

And make sure your json file is valid: http://jsonlint.com/